# Python socket throws multiple exceptions

Tags: python, sockets

Our code is on python 2.4.2, in an embedded Linux environment (ARM).

When attempting to get a socket connection and the server refuses the connection I get multiple errors.

The first one is a socket.error - Connection refused. Which is handled in an exception block.

Immediately after the caller gets an exception 'data'

Relevant code is :

```
class CTM_TX_Service(object):

    def __init__(self, synch):
        """ Create a new CTM_TX_SERVICE.
        """
        global gSynch

        gSynch = synch
        gSynch.logDebug("CTM TX SERVICE init")
        self.synch=synch

    def send(self, data, IP, port=CTM_CMD_PORT):
        try:
            gSynch.logDebug("CTM TX SERVICE sending message " + str(data))
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(3.0) #wait for 3 second before timeout
            s.connect((IP, port))
            s.send(data)
            reply = s.recv(1024)
            s.close()
        except Exception, e:
            gSynch.logError("CTM TX Send exception: "+str(e))
```

The caller's code:

```
def SendOperatingMode(self, mode):
    self.TrouncerListLock.acquire()
    for interface in self.activeTrouncerList:
        try:
            cmd = "mode %d" % mode
            ip = interface['ip']
            self.synch.logInfo("Send CTM command: '%s' to IP %s" % (cmd, ip))
            self.synch.ctmTx.send(cmd, ip)
        except Exception, e:
            self.synch.logError("SendOperatingMode exception: %s" % str(e))
    self.synch.logDebug("SetMode done")
    self.TrouncerListLock.release()
```

And the corresponding logs:

```
Aug  6 21:49:38 TROUNCER user.info Synch: Send CTM command: mode 0 to IP 192.168.11.13
Aug  6 21:49:38 TROUNCER user.debug Synch: CTM TX SERVICE sending message mode 0
Aug  6 21:49:39 TROUNCER user.info Synch: Send CTM command: mode 0 to IP 192.168.10.12
Aug  6 21:49:39 TROUNCER user.debug Synch: CTM TX SERVICE sending message mode 0
Aug  6 21:49:39 TROUNCER user.err Synch: CTM TX Send exception: (111, 'Connection refused')
Aug  6 21:49:39 TROUNCER user.err Synch: SendOperatingMode exception: 'data'
Aug  6 21:49:40 TROUNCER local7.notice dvcs: cSpd,   373: Flagging Server Down: 192.168.11.26:49152
```

The last log message "Set mode done" is never seen which leads me to believe that the caller's function is also exiting out before the end.

Comment: You may want to log the rest of the information in the exception: the class name and the stack trace, in addition to the object's string representation.  That may tell you more, including where the exception was raised.

Comment: You should generally not catch naked exceptions.

Comment: @dsh A previous version was using a thread and I read that handling tracebacks are a no no in threads. I can see if I get more information out. The one that I really question is the 'data' exception ! I'll see about adding type.

Comment: If you are using threads, then you'll want the logging to log the thread id as well so that you can see what messages go together in sequence and what ones don't.